# Align div into a list element like a grid

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this structure:

```
<ul class="wrap-accordionblk">
<li class="accordionblk-item">
<div class="accordionblk-header">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>ID SESSIONE</label><strong>MM-00120853</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>DATA</label>31/01/16</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>NOME SESSIONE</label>ferrarif-2B0000118188</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>ANNO STAGIONE</label>AI 2015</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>TIPO ORDINE</label>2B</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>N° CAPI</label>1</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
            <label>VALORE </label>€ 94,92</div>
        <div class="infoblk">
        </div>

        </div>
</div>  
</li>

<li class="accordionblk-item">
    <div class="accordionblk-header">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>ID SESSIONE</label><strong>MM-00120854</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>DATA</label>29/01/16</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>NOME SESSIONE</label>ferrarif-2B0000118030</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>ANNO STAGIONE</label>AI 2015</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>TIPO ORDINE</label>2B</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>N° CAPI</label>1</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
                <label>VALORE </label>€ 94,92</div>
            <div class="infoblk">
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>  
</li>
</ul>
```

I have the problem that, if the session name (NOME SESSIONE) have a different number of characters, I have a grid with column not aligned. You can see the result in this jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vekeu85d/).

How I can modify css to make columns aligned each others also if the string have a different number of characters?

Comment: Can you change your `markup`?, as for this type of content `table` element might be more appropriate. If not you might need to resort to "fixing" width of this elements..

Comment: I cannot change elements. A grafical agency made the css on the elements base... I know a table would be the best solution...

Comment: I have to say they screwed it up :) Is that what you're after - https://jsfiddle.net/vekeu85d/1/ ?

Comment: You could also look into Bootstrap, which makes use of rows and columns without (necessarily) using tables.

Comment: you could add max-width and word-wrap

Comment: @robjez what changes you made?

Comment: @sharkbait - it's at the end of `css` you provided - `.row-fluid div:nth-child(3) { width: 100px; color: red; }`. With this approach you don't need to rely on classes, if you're sure of order of these cells.

Comment: I'd definitely stick with a class. It's more reliable if you have to change the order of the cells.

Comment: Ok so you say to me the best solution is fix the size of the infoblk in pixels?

Comment: @Lewis one objection to that is that OP seems to not have control over the `html`, so I've excluded option of adding class inside of `html` code

Comment: I wouldn't do it in pixels if you are concerned about responsiveness. Percentages in this scenario would work better. Unless of course responsiveness isn't an issue, then go for it.

Comment: @robjez Fair point. :)

Comment: Ok thanks to all!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding width: 14.25%; to the class .infoblk fixes this. Is there a reason you don't want to assign widths?

```
.infoblk{
  width: 14.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really cant use a table then give them extra css classes for each column setting widths? Or put each column of divs inside an outer div so they match the width of the larger inner.

```
<div class="column1">
    <div class="infoblk"></div>
    <div class="infoblk"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show me how I have to do? I thought to put a `style=width:20%;` in the `<div>` element.

Comment: Can you not edit the css? You could use percentages like in @Lewis answer or if you want the columns to be different sizes then set them individually.